# How to track a transaction? (exchanger -> MetaMask)

Tags: ether, metamask, etherscan

Yesterday i sent some ether from my bitstamp account to an address I've created on MetaMask/Chrome.

Bitstamp tells transaction done:

```
Transaction ID (TXID): 0xef7b75aa80f2124b89a83c609f23d8a8cd4d66f5e429879146f16fdb5ce2a530
```

Etherscan gives status "1":

> https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=transaction&action=getstatus&txhash=0xef7b75aa80f2124b89a83c609f23d8a8cd4d66f5e429879146f16fdb5ce2a530

```
status  "1"
message "OK"
result  
isError "0"
errDescription  ""
```

But my MetaMask account did not receive anything!
Address: 0xE05175635921B08B4124421788029A938ea24A1E

Etherscan shows no transaction for it.
Where are the ethers?

Thx a lot for any tipp ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having issues with my transactions too. What gas price did you use?
Apparently [kittens clogged](https://www.coindesk.com/loveable-digital-kittens-clogging-ethereums-blockchain/) the network recently.

Try resending your transaction with higher gas price. You can get an idea about the network status and required gas price from here: https://ethgasstation.info/